# Remember me в Symfony 3.1.4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony3

Друзья, коллеги приветствую!

Есть проект на Symfony 3.1.4. Есть пользователи, есть стандартная форма авторизации и проверки.

В app/config/config.yml

```
session:
  handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
  save_path: ~
  cookie_lifetime: 2678400 # месяц
  gc_probability: 0
  cookie_path: /
```

В app/config/security.yml

```
main:
  ...
  remember_me:
    secret: '%secret%'
    always_remember_me: true
    lifetime: 2678400
    remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
    path: /
    domain: ~
```

При авторизации ставится кука, expiration на месяц вперед, вроде все отлично. Но если через некоторое время обновить (честно не знаю через сколько), сайт просит заново авторизоваться. Кука пропадает.

Почему так происходит, помогите пожалуйста.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: может потому что в remember_me нужно свой  lifetime ставить

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/remember_me.html

Comment: Извините, чет упустил описание, есть время жизни

remember_me:
        secret: '%secret%'
        always_remember_me: true
        lifetime: 2678400
        remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
        path: /
        domain: ~

Comment: Где сессии хранятся? Уверены, что они не удаляются каким-либо способом? Частая ошибка начинающих – хранить сессии в `cache`-директории, чистить кэш и искать потом свои сессии...